# Sympy: how to always print variables first, then constants?

Tags: sympy

I am doing some matrix manipulation, and I would like that my variables are always present in alphabetical order (which they are, as far as I can tell), there are no spaces, and that any constants are printed last.

How can I ensure these last two requirements? No spaces is trivial to do in my final formatting step, so I'm not too concerned about it, but the constant-ordering would be a little harder.

An example:

```
import sympy
from sympy import symbols, Matrix, Rational, pprint
from sympy import init_printing
init_printing()

mm = Matrix([[-1,0,0], [-1,1,0], [0,0,-1]])
tt = Matrix([Rational(6,12), Rational(0,12), Rational(6,12)])

x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
r = Matrix([x, y, z])

rp = mm * r + tt

pprint(rp)


# Currently:
# ⎡1/2 - x⎤
# ⎢       ⎥
# ⎢-x + y ⎥
# ⎢       ⎥
# ⎣1/2 - z⎦

# Wanted:
# ⎡-x+1/2⎤
# ⎢      ⎥
# ⎢ -x+y ⎥
# ⎢      ⎥
# ⎣-z+1/2⎦
```

The final aim will be to output the matrix values to file as strings, such as:

```
'-x+1/2,-x+y,-z+1/2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
init_printing(order="grevlex")
```